# SQLAlchemy ORM: modify the columns returned from a query

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

If I've got an SQLAlchemy ORM query:

```
admin_users = Session.query(User).filter_by(is_admin=True)
```

Is it possible to modify the columns returned by that query?

For example, so that I could select only the `User.id` column, and use that in a sub query:

```
admin_email_addresses = Session.query(EmailAddress)\
    .filter(EmailAddress.user_id.in_(admin_users.select_columns(User.id))
```

Note: the `.values()` method will not work, as it executes the query and returns an iterable of results (so, ex, `EmailAddress.user_id.in_(admin_users.values(User.id))` will perform two queries, not one).

I know that I could modify the first query to be `Session.query(User.id)`, but I'm specifically wondering how I could modify the columns returned by a query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I feel your pain on the `values()` thing.   In 0.6.5 I added `with_entities()` which is just like `values()` except doesn't iterate:

```
q = q.with_entities(User.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `Address.user_id` defines a `ForeignKey`, the query below will do the job more efficiently compared to `IN` operator:

```
admin_email_addresses = session.query(EmailAddress).\
    join(User).filter(User.is_admin==True)
```

If you do not have a ForeignKey (although you should), you can specify the `join` condition explicitely:

```
admin_email_addresses = session.query(EmailAddress).\
    join(User, User.id==EmailAddress.user_id).filter(User.is_admin==True)
```

But if you really would like to do it with `in_` operator, here you go (note the `subquery`):

```
subq = session.query(User.id).filter(User.is_admin==True).subquery()
admin_email_addresses = session.query(EmailAddress).\
       filter(EmailAddress.user_id.in_(subq))
```

Comment: It's true that, in the example I provided, a `JOIN` is the correct solution. However, since it doesn't address the question I actually asked, I'm going to be accepting zzzeek's answer.