# How to replace columns in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the query:

```
q = Session.query(func.array_agg(Order.col))
```

The compiled query will be:

```
SELECT array_agg(order.col) FROM orders
```

I want dynamically replace the existing column. After replacing query have to be:

```
SELECT group_concat(orders.col) FROM orders
```

I have to use Session and model. I don't have to use SQLAlchemy core. I don't have to use subqueries. And, of course, there can be some other columns, but I need to replace only one. I tried to replace objects in `column_descriptions` property, I tried to use `q.selectable.replace` (or something like this, sorry, but I don't remember right names) and I didn't get right result.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677514/sqlalchemy-orm-modify-the-columns-returned-from-a-query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right method:

```
q = Session.query(func.array_agg(Order.col)) 

q.with_entities(func.group_concat(Order.col))

SELECT group_concat(orders.col) FROM orders
```